# Windows 10 upgrade to version 1607 keeps failing

Tags: windows, windows-10

Upgrade to 1607 keeps failing. Any ideas?

> 0xC1900101 - 0x3000D
>
> The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with
> an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @run5k, the dup is wrong. He can't upgrade to 1607 becasue it fails during the upgrade. This is a different issue compared to WU can't see 1607

Comment: @magicandre1981, fair enough.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [explained the error here:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors)

> **Code** 0xC1900101 - 0x3000D
>
> **Cause** Installation failed during the FIRST_BOOT phase while attempting the MIGRATE_DATA operation. **This can occur due to a problem
>   with a display driver.**

And this is what Microsoft suggest to fix the error:

> Disconnect all peripheral devices that are connected to the system,
>   except for the mouse, keyboard and display. Update or uninstall the
>   display driver.

So try all steps, remove all devices, uninstall the GPU driver and try to do the upgrade.

If this still fails, create a feedback entry in [Feedback Hub App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n) and attach a ZIP of the folder `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\` to the feedback.

Also click on the share button after you created the feedback and post the link here as comment. I'll submit it to my Microsoft contacts so that they can look at the issue.